# Jquery .prop() not workin

Tags: jquery

I have this code...

```
 function roundtrip() {
   //alert("Round Trip");
   $("#checkoutdate").prop("disabled", false);
   $("#btncheckoutdate").show();
 }
 function onewaytrip() {
   //alert("One Way Trip");
   $("#checkoutdate").prop("disabled", true);
   $("#btncheckoutdate").hide();
 }
```

n the html code is

```
<input type="radio" name="trip_type" id="trip_type" onclick = "return onewaytrip()" value="One_way"> One Way Trip
<input type="radio" name="trip_type" id="trip_type" onclick = "return roundtrip()" checked="checked" value="round_trip"> Round Trip

<label name="depaturedate">Departure Date</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input id="checkindate" class="font11textbox" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="position: relative;" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" name="checkindate">
<img id="btncheckindate" border="0" name="btncheckindate" alt="select date" src="images/calendar1.gif">
&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<label name="returndate">Return</label>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input id="checkoutdate" class="font11textbox" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="position: relative;" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" name="checkoutdate">
<img id="btncheckoutdate" border="0" name="btncheckoutdate" alt="select date" src="images/calendar1.gif">
</br>
```

The aim is to hide/display the calender image n to enable/disable the inputbox on click of the respective radio buttons.

but i'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'prop' of null.
```

it's really bothering me. The code is real simple for the error. I need sum help here.

Comment: be sure you have `jQuery` included, and what version are you using?

Comment: Don't use id more than one time. You used id="trip_type" as twice

Comment: Seems to be working just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dcDbP/) - did you place the functions after the elements in the DOM, and not inside a document ready function (scope) ?

Comment: other than jquery what are the other libraries used in the page?

Comment: Did you load jQuery, and not some other library like Prototype.js?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using and are you sure that the `checkoutdate` is the actual id that is rendered in the browser?

Comment: @Spokey:yes Jquery is loaded alrite.

Comment: @Niklas: I'm using JQ 1.8

Comment: Could it be that you have this code in the `<head>` section and that the code runs before the elements are created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using proper event handlers :

```
<input type="radio" name="trip_type" id="oneway" value="One_way"> One Way Trip
<input type="radio" name="trip_type" id="roundtrip" value="round_trip" checked> Round Trip
```

js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[name="trip_type"]').on('change', function() {
        state = this.checked && this.id == 'oneway';

        $("#checkoutdate").prop("disabled", state);
        $("#btncheckoutdate").toggle(state);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dcDbP/1/)

Comment: since `$("#checkoutdate")` is returning `null` we could probably assume that `$` is not `jQuery` object

Comment: @ArunPJohny - That should cause a `$ is not defined` error, not an element does not exist error? Changed my answer to accound for other libraries overwriting `$` as well !

Comment: @adeneo No, `$` can still be defined by another script. Before jQuery, `$` was a common alias for `document.getElementById`: `function $(id) {return document.getElementById(id); }`.

Comment: @RobW - my current answer should work no matter what, as long as jQuery is loaded, so it should solve the issue and get rid of the inline JS, problem solved.

Comment: @adeneo Your answer works indeed, my "No" was referring to [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771994/jquery-prop-not-workin#comment24165069_16772153) "That should cause a `$ is not defined` error".